# HDFS IO Failure "path is not a file"

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, h2o

I recently updated my h2o from 3.6.0.8 to 3.10.0.9 on hadoop and am using the python api. Previously (using 3.6) I used the following command to load in a model I had saved:

```
model_to_load = h2o.load_model('hdfs://nameservice1/path/to/model/model_directory')
```

I now use the same command (in 3.10) and get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /path/to/model/model_directory
```

I tried downgrading back to 3.6.0.8 and it works just fine, just as it did before. Within the directory I have a file for each tree (this is a random forest model), two model metric files, and two files one named

```
__h2o_bin.mbin
```

and one named

```
model_directory.bin
```

I tried using each of those in the load_model path but no luck.

Has anyone experienced this and do you know the right path I should use to load my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2O binary models are not necessarily compatible between major versions of H2O.  If you want to load a model using H2O 3.10.*, that model will have to have been trained using 3.10 rather than 3.6.

Comment: Ah rats, ok. Thanks!

Comment: When this is the cause you get an error message explicitly saying "version mismatch".  This sounds more like a change in the behaviour of h2o.load_model() between 3.6 and 3.10?